# Angular 2 component not filling the screen

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

My root component does not fill the screen in height. Root component template is the following:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" id="tool">
  <div fxLayout="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div fxFlex="10" fxFlexAlign="center">
      <md-icon (click)="navigateBack()" [hidden]="!showBackNavigation">keyboard_arrow_left</md-icon>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="70" fxFlexAlign="center">
    <span>
      {{headerTitle}}
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

What I was trying to do is to set min-height : 100% for all tags but this didn't work. If I set the height in pixels it will update properly. How can I make the content to fill window's height ?

[Screenshot with HTML layout and application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp9mO.png)

Answer (score 6):

You likely also need to set `min-height: 100%;` to the parent elements of this element, as they may not be by default. Or you can use `min-height: 100vh;` instead, and that will make the element 100% of the viewport height, instead of  trying to fill 100% of the parent.